# Google App Engine and Cloud SQL: Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet' SQL 2nd Gen

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I'm getting an error similar to other posts in this subject.
I tried switching from 1st gen to 2nd gen SQL server (both on us-central1), but it still doesn't work.

I copied my CLOUDSQL_PROJECT from the url on the top of my project.
I copied my CLOUDSQL_INSTANCE from the proprieties part in the SQL page.

In my main.py, I'm trying to run Google sample code, and it doesn't work (locally it does, of course):

```
if os.getenv('SERVER_SOFTWARE', '').startswith('Google App Engine/'):
        db = MySQLdb.connect(
            unix_socket='/cloudsql/{}:{}'.format(
                CLOUDSQL_PROJECT,
                CLOUDSQL_INSTANCE),
            user=user,passwd=password)
    # When running locally, you can either connect to a local running
    # MySQL instance, or connect to your Cloud SQL instance over TCP.
    else:
        db = MySQLdb.connect(host=host,user=user,passwd=password)
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute('SHOW VARIABLES')

for r in cursor.fetchall():
    self.response.write('{}\n'.format(r))
```

Comment: you can only write to the response once, apart from anything else.

Comment: Fixed somehow!I 
tried manipulating the CLOUDSQL_INSTANCE and it worked.
i just removed the project-id part from it and it worked
so for example, if the project id is hello-word-123
and the INSTANCE name (from the SQL proprerties page) is hello-world-123:us-central1:sqlsomething3
then you need to change it to us-central1:sqlsomething3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation is slightly outdated. You should be able to always use the "Instance connection name" property from the SQL properties page to construct the unix socket path; just append that value after the "/cloudsql/" prefix.

For second generation, the connection format is project:region:name. In your example, it maps to "hello-world-123:us-central1:sqlsomething3", and the unix socket path is "/cloudsql/hello-world-123:us-central1:sqlsomething3".

Comment: To add to Tony's answer, the relevant documentation about App Engine connectivity is entitled [Connecting from Google App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/app-engine-connect#gaev2-csqlv2).

Comment: Great answer. Had to search for this.